# Optimize SELECT without WHERE clause SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

**Main Question:**

Is there anything that will increase the performance of `SELECT * FROM TABLEX` queries?  As far as I can tell, the only way to increase performance is to hope you can cache the table by repeating the call.

**Real Problem:**

Right now we have some software that we need to map in data from our db.  Currently that data is stored in tables that are populated immediately before the import.  We have pretty heavily optimized the process of populating the tables, and I just want to make sure I'm not missing anything that will optimize the reading part.  I am fairly certain the software uses a `SELECT *` type query since any indices I add do not get used during the import.

**EDIT:**

From the trace, an example query that seems to take a fair amount of time (9500ms) is

```
SELECT 
    Item_Code as ExternalId, Item_Code as Name, 
    Item_Desc as Description, Source, TransferQty 
FROM MAP_Item
```

However, the same query is under a second when I run it locally.  Additionally, the schema for `MAP_Item` is `Item_Code | Item_Desc | Source | TransferQty` with no indices.

Comment: That's really not enough information to give any useful answer. You need to include at least the table & index structures, the exact SQL you are using and the query plan.

Comment: Attach the sql server profiler and see what queries are being executed.  You can then add covering indexes where appropriate.  But without knowing the tables and the exact query, we won't be able to know where the performance issues are occurring.

Comment: An index won't help you unless you specify an Order by Clause. What are you doing with the data after you select it?

Comment: An index makes no difference if it's a plain select * from table. (Indexes are useful when join, where, order by etc.)

Comment: @MichaelG Good advice!  I didn't realize that tool was available.  I will post the queries and schema once I have the results.

Comment: @MichaelG Thanks to the trace, I realized the bottleneck is something called 'Audit Logout'.  I'm going to close the question while I google that.

Comment: Make it as a stored procedure? What is told to me is that with very large datasets stored procedures have a higher performance, because they don't have to be parsed by the dbms. Though I'm not an expert... Yet! ;)

Comment: I don't have access to the program running the query, I just want to make the DB as quick as possible in responding.  I don't think there is much I can do, I just wanted to see if there was something I didn't know about optimizing simple `SELECT` statements.